# Does SAS create temp files while import in another location rather than the one specified

Tags: import, sas

I am trying to import huge 100GB data, i end up getting errors such as space not available, i am wondering if this is happening because it gets stored into some temp space on my PC?

My library reference is to a server.

Comment: And where does the 100GB data come from? Isn't it also possible that the SAS work and/or whatever library you are importing to on your server does not have 100GB storage available?

Comment: the 100GB data is a txt file stored in the server and the server has the available space but SAS work does not

Comment: Then there you have it. You could work around it by importing your data in increments (N lines at a time) using a loop and appending it each time to the result in a library that has the storage space to host your data.

Comment: What do you mean by "import"?  If you run a data step to read a file it should not write anywhere other then where you tell it to.

Comment: I am running a data step infile but for some reason it is creating a temp file in C where it gets deleted end of session

Comment: Are you trying to run `PROC IMPORT` on a  100GB file? Why? Don't you know what is in the file?

Comment: i dont know whats in the file, its a new file which i recently got.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your server configuration.

You see in this manner, first check performance with:

proc options group=performance;
run;

then

In the config file you should find for example:
[SAS CONFIG]/Lev1/SASApp/sasv9_usermods.cfg
[SAS HOME]/SASFoundation/9.3/sasv9_local.cfg

You should fine a option like :

```
-bufsize 64K
```

source: http://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=bisag&docsetTarget=p1n3ivrea2b8fgn1at5j88gyteqj.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en

https://www.zencos.com/blog/sas-administration-change-the-options-to-get-more-performance/

I guess increasing the buffer can help a bit and I suggest you to split the file in several files with linux it's super easy :

```
split --bytes=1000M /path/to/file.csv /path/to/csv/filesplit_
```

And then you can create generic import in a macro function and import like this :

```
%import(filesplit_1);
%import(filesplit_2);
%import(filesplit_3);
%import(filesplit_4);
..
```

And after each import, you can insert the data into a DBMS system like oracle.
During your insert with proc sql path through, don't forget to use the BULKLOAD option.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about a text file you are reading then just write it directly to the location that has space.

```
filename in '/location1/bigfile.csv';
libname out '/location2/mysasdata';
data out.bigfile ;
  infile in dsd firstobs=2 truncover ;
  length var1 8 var2 $100 ..... ;
  input var1 var2 .... ;
run;
```